# Algorithm that takes input desc. of two PDAs and outputs intersection of langs. recognized by two PDAs

Tags: computability, automata, context-free-grammar

Does there exist an algorithm which takes as input the descriptions of two pushdown automata, $P1$ and $P2$, and prints the description of another pushdown automaton which recognizes the intersection of the languages recognized by $P1$ and $P2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the intersection of two CFLs is not context free.  Can you come up with an example?  Mouse over the grey area below for *an* example. (It is a theorem that the intersection of a context free language with a *regular language* is context free.)

So the description of a PDA recognizing $P_1 \cap P_2$ does not necessarily exist.

> The go-to example for showing this is, let $$P_1 = \{a^n b^n c^*\} \text{ and } P_2 = \{a^* b^n c^n \}$$